# push data from Microsot Dynamics CRM to windows azure service bus Queues using C# plugin code

Tags: dynamics-crm-2013, azure-servicebus-queues

We are trying to push data to Azure Service Bus Queue when a case is created in "Dynamics CRM Online". We have implemented it using a plugin by registering it with Plugin Registration Tool.

The error is as follows

> WindowsAzurePlugin.QueueProcess: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.ServiceBus, Version=2.1.0.0, I tied changing the versions to 2.6,1.5 and 1.0 but still it is showing same type that file not found exception error

Comment: Is this CRM Online or On-Premise?